# How can I load the templates from a module?

Tags: plugin-development, templating, modules

I'm creating a module that contains some predefined templates. How can I load them directly out of the vendor folder? I've tried doing

```
Event::on(View::class, View::EVENT_REGISTER_SITE_TEMPLATE_ROOTS, function(RegisterTemplateRootsEvent $event) {
    if (is_dir($baseDir = $this->getBasePath().DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'templates')) {
        $event->roots[$this->id] = $baseDir;
    }
});
```

That part seems to be working, cause if I dump it, I get:

```
[
    'my-module' => '/app/modules/mymodule/src/templates'
]
```

In my module, I have a `templates/test.twig`

But when I do `mysite.com/test`, I still get a 404.

I've also tried a different approach, in the routes.php, I put:

```
'test' => ['template' => '@modules/my-module/test'],
```

Still nothing.

Is there something I could differently?

Comment: I'm not sure this is what you're looking for, but did you already tried something like `Craft::$app->getView()->renderTemplate('_mySection/entry', array_merge($variables))`? Using this, you could get your template content generated within your plugin.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answer from [@robin-schambach](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/users/5557/robin-schambach)

```
It's not possible the way you do it... or the way you are trying to do it
During site requests only templates from your template folder can be loaded
otherwise it would be a high security issue
```